# Citations: How to deal with error in the original text caused by repeated word or misspelling?

Tags: citation

I'm reading an article I could potentially use for my thesis, but I've come across several errors already. I'm curious on how to do it if I really had to use the words from the original text.

I wouldn't want to use [sic] as [How to deal with quoting a grammatical error?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11857/how-to-deal-with-quoting-a-grammatical-error) suggests, because it's distracting and makes me look mean.

So if the original text says "Finally, we may have **puctual** obligations" would it be within the norm to just write it as "Finally, we may have [**punctual**] obligations"?

Another problem I see is if the original text repeats a word (or forgets a word from a different formulation). So what if the text said "Finally, we may **may** have punctual obligations"? Dropping the word would be a misquote, but adding (...) wouldn't make sense and again would distract the reader.

This isn't really a problem I need to deal with, because I think the solution in this case would be not to use a direct citation and use my own words instead to avoid repeating the mistake. However, it's possible that error like this may appear in text which cannot be rewritten.

This is the source material: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5625356/

Comment: Suggested transfer to https://academia.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would note that, in the supplied context, "punctual" does not seem to be a good fit.  Perhaps some other term was intended?

Comment: I'm curious about the original source. Normally something needs to get through proofreaders before being published. I also wonder if it's a translation.

Comment: The source indeed meant "punctual". It doesn't make sense in the piece I posted, because I didn't supply any context. It was at the end of the list explaining different types of obligations. I know for sure, because at the beginning, the author stated the types of obligations in one sentence.

Comment: I think what Hot Licks means is that while one type of obligation is the obligation for punctuality, the obligation itself is not punctual- it is not a punctual obligation.  Perhaps they are ***timeliness*** obligations.

Comment: @Jim I think Hot Licks means, that like this it makes little sense (which I agree with), so perhaps I'm trying to correct the error incorrectly. However, the obligations are indeed punctual, because they are linked to one specific point in the process. It sounds weird, but I believe the authors choice makes sense. The obligations are divided based on when they are in effect

Comment: @AdelaidaClarke - So you are saying that the obligations arrive on time? At some point in the process an obligation pops up for someone where none existed before?

Comment: @Jim pretty much. The obligation didn't exist before a certain point in the process was reached and it will cease to exist afterwards. Instead of saying "obligations arrive on time", I think a more fitting definition would be that the obligation belongs to that certain point in time. It cannot occur any other time. I'm not a native speaker, but I believe the word was constructed correctly for that purpose. Perhaps the author could have used "point obligations", but I think this would also have other perhaps more incorrect implications

Answer (score 2):

If you are correcting only a few small and obvious typos, it may be considered acceptable these days to do so silently.

For example, if you follow the *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), the following is from section 13.7:

> Although in a direct quotation the wording should be reproduced exactly, the following changes are generally permissible to make a passage fit into the syntax and typography of the surrounding text . . .
>
> 6. Obvious typographic errors may be corrected silently (without comment or *sic*), unless the passage quoted is from an older work or a manuscript or other unpublished source where idiosyncrasies of spelling are generally preserved. If spelling and punctuation are modernized or altered for clarity, readers must be so informed in a note, in a preface, or elsewhere.

(Several other points were made, but I elided them for the sake of brevity.)

---

Of course, if you're writing a thesis, I would check with your instructor or advisor to see what style guide should be followed.

Comment: This is very sound advice: follow it, especially the last bit!